# How to fix java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException when using integer.parseint

Tags: java, javafx, parseint

Im trying to make a simple calculation program but i keep getting this error whenever I try to run the code. How can i avoid this?

```
TextField inputOne = new TextField("Input first data");


        // Making output 1
        int inputNumber = Integer.parseInt(inputOne.getText());
```

Always get error message java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at line 25 where the parse int is placed

Comment: `InvocationTargetException`s always have a _cause_ (look at the `Caused by:`s in the stack trace). In your case, it's likely a `NumberFormatException`.

Comment: @BigBoi, You will increase the probability of getting a response, providing more contextual information about your problem. Take a look to this post: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getText() function returns the input value of the user, or the "Input first data" String? if it returns the input value of the user then it is probably a NumberFormatException that you should handle, else it is because the String mentioned is the mistake.